# I'm unable to trigger a XMLHttpRequest with the onreadystatechange method is the better method to use

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an html table of names and I want to be able to click on a name and retrieve additional details of the person and display them in an 'Alert' popup. I plan to use the XMLHttpRequest to send the name to a php file to process it. I can retrieve the name from the table with no trouble but I have run some diagnostic tests and cannot seem to trigger the XMLHttpRequest using the onreadystatechange method.
This is my code that retrieves the name:-

```
function getDetails(x){
        var tr1 = x.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var td1 = x.cellIndex;
        var table = document.getElementById("selectedTeams");
        //Diagnostic 
        //document.getElementById("tr1").innerHTML = "1st Row index is: " + tr1; 
        //document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = "1st Column index is: " + td1;  
        player = table.rows[tr1].cells[td1].innerHTML;
        player = player.replace("<b>", "");
        player = player.replace("</b>", "")
        player = player.trim();
        //Diagnostic 
        //document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = "The player selected is: " + player;
        getName(player);
        //Diagnostic 
        //alert("This will be the "+ player + " details");
    }
```

This gets the player's name. It works well. The player's name is then passed to the `getName()` function. From my diagnostics it does not trigger the onreadystatechange and go through the subsequent function. Am I using the right method here or is there a more appropriate one and is the rest of the code ok. The code for the getName() function is :-

```
function getName(str){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                //document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "playerDetails.php?q= " + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            //Diagnostic 
            //alert("after onreadystatechange");
        }
        //Diagnostic 
       //alert("after function");
    }
```

Comment: move the open/send calls outside of the callback

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue, but in the *getDetails* function, consider using [*textContent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of messing with *innerHTML*. It returns just the text, no tags. Also, if the name is a key for your database, consider adding it as a *data* attribute so *getName* isn't constrained by presentation or other factors that apply to displayed text.

Comment: Thank you, it works okay now . I should have seen that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've put the `open` and `send` calls *inside* of the `onreadystatechange` event handler, which will never be run until `open` and `send` are called. See the catch-22?
Fix this issue by moving the calls to `open` and `send` from the `onreadystatechange` event handler into the enclosing `getName` function body like this:

```js
function getName(str) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
      //document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      alert(this.responseText);
    }
    //Diagnostic 
    //alert("after onreadystatechange");
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "playerDetails.php?q= " + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  //Diagnostic 
  //alert("after function");
}
```